# nunit-console shipped with Mono is deprecated, please use the Nunit Nuget package or some other form of acquiring NUnit

Tags: macos, ssh, mono, nunit-console

**How to run NUnit test on console on MAC OSX (Mono 5.18.1) over ssh**

[image]

I have a test dll on MAC OS X which needs to run using nunit-console over ssh connection. However it gives error that Nunit-console shipped with Mono is deprecated.

Also tried Nunit3-console.exe, but it gives error (only when run over ssh)

CODE:

```
"/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/mono" "/Users/TestData/NUnit.Console-3.9.0/nunit3-console.exe" "/Users/TestData/UITest.QPTTests/bin/Debug/UITest.QPTTests.dll"
```

ERROR:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : ApplicationName='mono', CommandLine='--runtime=v4.0.30319 "/Users/TestData/NUnit.Console-3.9.0/nunit-agent.exe" b10715dd-58ed-4f6a-9220-6f9a52a2cXXX tcp://137.0.0.1:5125/TestAgency --pid=2129 --work=/Users', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= Cannot find the specified file
```

Answer (score 1):

Try execute `source /etc/profile` command before u run unit-console
In your case:

```
source /etc/profile; "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/mono" "/Users/TestData/NUnit.Console-3.9.0/nunit3-console.exe" "/Users/TestData/UITest.QPTTests/bin/Debug/UITest.QPTTests.dll"
```